# Unable to start service in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to run a service by using following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

This code works fine on versions older than Android 6.0 Marshmallow. But here on Android 6.0, the service never gets created. `startService()` is returning `null`. I'm calling it from an Activity in the same package. My manifest is like:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.example.app2.MyService"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </service>
```

Also my application is not crashing, it's just the service is not starting (not created).

Comment: post your MyService class!

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing any device hardware features(Camera, Storage, Location etc) in the Service.  You need to ask runtime permission in the Marshmallow devices. Otherwise, it will make a crash if your compile SDK version >=23. Please paste your Crash log or Service code for further clarification.

Please check the link to implement the feature:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Please edit your question with Service implementation

Comment: What is your compile SDK version?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23 and buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Comment: So you need to implement Runtime permission for Marshmallow. I hope you required some permission for run this Service.

Comment: i'm registering a broadcast receiver there, is it creating the problem

Comment: If you are not willing to do the implementation, you can downgrade the compile SDK version as 22, it will work. But it's as like a workaround. Not the preferred one.

Comment: I think broadcast receiver won't required any permission. But if you are using CALENDAR, CAMERA, CONTACTS, LOCATION, MICROPHONE, PHONE, SENSORS, SMS or STORAGE  inside it, it will block onReceive()

Comment: Please mark the right answer if you think its right. Also please upvote

Answer (score 0):

Once I was having the same problem. It was a very small and stupid mistake. I had given `<service>` tag outside `<application>` tag in manifest.xml. After moving it inside `<application>` tag service started successfully. Check for any typos in service name also. Hope it helps!